# Kotlin Internal Error java.lang.IllegalStateException with Jetbrains Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, kotlin-gradle-plugin, jetbrains-compose

Hi I'm new to kotlin and trying to get a Jetpack compose desktop calculator application up and running. I wrote some JUnit tests and attempted to run them, but I am met with an internal error instead. This is the IntelliJ output:

```
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:618)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:130)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:170)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:431)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1500)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void registerProjectComponents(com.intellij.mock.MockProject, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.CompilerConfiguration)' of interface org.jetbrains.kotlin.compiler.plugin.ComponentRegistrar.
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:610)
    ... 28 more
```

I've spent a few hours trying to get the right dependencies in my `build.gradle.kts` file. Right now I have:

```
dependencies {
    kotlinCompilerClasspath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha02")
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
    implementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1")
    kotlinCompilerClasspath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21")
}
```

Another post suggested using Compose version 1.0.0-beta08, which I tried and got:

```
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.compose', version: '1.0.0-beta08'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

with no further information. 1.0.0-alpha3 has been the only version to successfully build. If you have thoughts on this, let me know, else I can ask it in a new question.

I'm running Kotlin 1.5.21, Jetbrains Compose version 1.0.0-alpha3 and I have the maven repository set to "https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev" as is recommended in several forums. If you have any resources I may check out, or know of a fix, I feel as though I've exhausted my options -- please leave me a comment, thanks.

Comment: `1.0.0-beta08` is beta of Android Compose, Compose for Desktop is not yet in betta, the latest version is `1.0.0-alpha3`, that's why that suggestion you're talking about is irrelevant. I suggest you [create an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) on JetBrains issue tracker to get faster response, as it's not yet much popular and SO may not help you here.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks for the response. Good to know that I should be working with `1.0.0-alpha3`, that's some peace of mind. I submitted an issue on YouTrack, but do you know of any communities I could join to ask questions like these, or about Kotlin/Compose/Android/etc?

Comment: Yes, you can [join](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up) kotlin slack, and ask in `#compose-desktop` channel.